# Semi, third, quarter circle and other compound style symbols in QGIS?

Tags: qgis, symbology, svg

I think I used quarter (and other) circles in QGIS in the past. But it might be as well that it was only in different software. Anyway now I am not able to find in symbols any option for compound (dispersed groups) style . Am I missing something?

If the only option is SVG symbols, do you know about some publicly available nice set of symbols to use for this?

Comment: you might be able to use some of the unicode characters and **Font Marker** styling (I think this only covers quarter circles in varying styles though). Also needs a font which supports it. You can see a list of [supported characters here](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/block/geometric_shapes/images.htm). Was this the sort of symbology you were after?

Comment: @StevenKay thank you for this idea. I have licence of MapInfo which has MapInfo Dispersed Groups font which has semi, third, quarter circle symbols and some others. That at this moment solve it for me. Though there is some juggling with offset etc. needed. Anyway I would like to have answer for my question without need of MapInfo licence.

Answer (score 3):

These have been added to the upcoming 2.16 release. There's options for 1/2, 1/3, 1/4 circles, and 1/2, 1/4 squares, and finally 1/2 rectangles.

Comment: Any chance it will be also part of long term release?

Comment: No - it's classed as a new feature, so isn't suitable for backporting to 2.14/2.8

Answer (score 2):

In case there are no free fonts with such symbols, it's possible to create SVGs using [InkScape](https://inkscape.org/en/) with the Circle/Arc tool ([Tutorial Here](https://inkscape.org/en/doc/tutorials/shapes/tutorial-shapes.en.html)).

I created this symbol in InkScape.

[image: pie slice in svg format]

I made an ellipse with <kbd>F5</kbd>, and <kbd>Ctrl-Drag</kbd> to make it a circle. I duplicated it using <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>D</kbd>, and edited the start/end angles on the duplicate. I then changed the styles on each layer.

You can edit the start/end angles to get precise fractions of a circle. These are in degrees, and East is 0, going clockwise.